# Create leaves of tree in Python

Tags: pandas

I have a large table of two columns in Excel. Column A is the NodeID, column B is the Parent. This table shows a tree.

```
NodeID| Parent
-------------
0    |     
1    |  0
2    |  0
3    |  1
4    |  1
5    |  3
6    |  3
7    |  2
8    |  2
```

I created the tree in Python/Graphviz but  now I would like to create chains according to the leaves of the tree in Pandas like this:

```
Parent| C1 | C2 | C3
---------------------
0     | 1  | 3  | 5
0     | 1  | 3  | 6
0     | 1  | 4  
0     | 2  | 7  
0     | 2  | 8
```

Which method can I use to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `recursion`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"NodeID": list(range(9)), "Parent": ['', 0,0,1,1,3,3,2,2]})

#define ultimate parent:
df2=df.loc[df["Parent"]=='', "NodeID"].to_frame()

def addLevel(actualDF, nodesDF):
    actualDF=actualDF.merge(nodesDF, how="left", left_on="NodeID", right_on="Parent", indicator=True).rename(columns={"NodeID_y": "NodeID", "NodeID_x": f"C{len(actualDF.columns)-1}"})
    if(actualDF.loc[actualDF["_merge"]=="both", "_merge"].count()>0):
        return addLevel(actualDF.drop(["_merge", "Parent"], axis=1), nodesDF)
    else:
        return actualDF.drop(["_merge", "Parent", "NodeID"], axis=1).rename(columns={"C0": "Parent"})

df=addLevel(df2, df)
```

Output:

```py
  Parent C1 C2   C3
0      0  1  3    5
1      0  1  3    6
2      0  1  4  NaN
3      0  2  7  NaN
4      0  2  8  NaN
```